# Visual Studio 22 - Error no me deja hacer nada con mi codigo y no se donde mirar ni que hacer, no se a que se refiere ni como salir de ahi

Tags: c#, vs

El valor no puede ser nulo. Nombre del parámetro: format

Instancias de este error (1)

1. Ocultar pila de llamadas

en System.String.FormatHelper(IFormatProvider provider, String format, ParamsArray args)
en System.String.Format(IFormatProvider provider, String format, Object[] args)
en Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.CodeDomDocDataAdapter.NotSupported(String srString, Object[] parameters)
en Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.CodeDomDocDataAdapter.get_Provider()
en Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.CodeDomDocDataAdapter.get_CompileUnit()
en Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.VSCodeDomDesignerLoader.PerformLoad(IDesignerSerializationManager serializationManager)
en System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.BasicDesignerLoader.BeginLoad(IDesignerLoaderHost host)

Comment: se rompio un form? seria interesante saber que estas tratando de abrir...

Comment: No, no ha sido un form. Al abrir la solucion me dice que faltan nuget parece ser que porque la ruta es demasiado larga y no encuentra un fichero. Gravedad Código Descripción Proyecto Archivo Línea Estado suprimido
Error NETSDK1112 no se descargó el paquete de tiempo de ejecución de Microsoft.Windows.SDK.NET.Ref. Pruebe a ejecutar una restauración de NuGet con RuntimeIdentifier "any". HolaMundoC C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.100\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.FrameworkReferenceResolution.targets 448 
Pero no se como hacer la restauracion NuGet con RuntimeIdentifier "any"